# gcc memory alignment using malloc

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, memory-alignment

I've the following struct:

```c
#define M 3

#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
struct my_btree_node {
    struct my_btree_node *pointers[M];
    unsigned char *keys[M - 1];
    int data[M - 1];
    unsigned char number_of_keys;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

The `sizeof(struct my_btree_node)` function returns a value of 49 byte for this struct. Does allocating memory for this struct using `malloc` return a 64 byte block because on 64 bit systems pointers are 16-byte-aligned or will it indeed be 49 bytes?

Is there a way to align memory with a smaller power of two than 16 and is it possible to get the true size of the allocated memory inside the application?

I want to reduce the number of padding bytes in order to save memory. My applications allocates millions of those structs and I do not want to waste memory.

Comment: What architecture (IA) are you compiling for?

Comment: What for? Aligning is good.

Comment: @CodeClown x86_64 architecture

Comment: @user4419802 To not use padding bytes in order to save memory

Comment: 15 bytes is not a big gain. But if you have too many structs, that is an array of structs, you may just split data in several arrays, as arrays are never padded.

Comment: You are confused. The alignment of the returned pointer has nothing to do with the amount of memory you request from the allocator. If you really, _really_ needed to save memory in this way, you'd request a large block (from malloc, mmap, hugepages, etc) and then manage it yourself.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Ok I get that. So only the pointer is 16 byte aligned and the memory requested has no additional padding?

Comment: The memory might or might not have any padding - you can't know that, and you're not guaranteed anything past what you requested.

Comment: Usually malloc'd memory is "padded" to have a whole number of "blocks" (whatever size they are). If you use MSVC you can find the actual size of block by `_msize(p);`

Answer (score 2):

[malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) is **defined** to

> The `malloc()` and `calloc()` functions return a pointer to the allocated
>          memory, which is **suitably aligned for any built-in type**.  On error,
>          these functions return `NULL`.  `NULL` may also be returned by a
>          successful call to `malloc()` with a *size* of zero, or by a successful
>          call to `calloc()` with *nmemb* or *size* equal to zero.

So a conforming implementation *has to* return a pointer aligned to the largest possible machine alignment (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), it is the [macro `__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html))

If you want less, implement your own allocation routine. You could for example allocate a large array of `char` and do your allocation inside it. That would be painful, perhaps slower (processors dislike unaligned data, e.g. because of [CPU cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) constraints), and probably not worthwhile (current computers have several gigabytes of RAM, so a few millions of hundred-byte sized data chunks is not a big deal).

BTW, `malloc` is practically *implemented* in the [C standard library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (but -on Linux at least- the compiler knows about it, thanks to `__attribute__`-s in [GNU glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) headers; so some internal optimizations inside [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) know and take care of calls to `malloc`).

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` uses internal heap-structure. It is implementation-dependent yet one may expect that the memory is allocated by a whole number of (internal) blocks. So usually it's not possible to allocate exactly 49 bytes by a single `malloc` call. You can build some subsystem of your own on top of `malloc` to do this, yet I see no reason why you may want it.

P.S. To reduce memory wasting, you can pre-allocate an array consisting of, say, 100 structs, when you need just one more, and return &a[i] until all free indexes are wasted. As arrays are never padded, the memory wasting would be reduced in about 100 times.