# How to determine the minimum alignment of malloc() results on my system?

Tags: c, memory-management, alignment, malloc, cross-platform

`malloc()` does not take an alignment constraint; but  for various reasons, its resulting allocations are actually aligned to some degree. For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29095583/1593077) tells us that `malloc()` results are required to be:

> suitably aligned for any built-in type

and that consequently, with GCC, the allocated addresses will be a multiple `__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__`. Ok, nice, but what about other compilers (specifically, clang, MSVC, ICC) - what do I use there? For 64-bit platforms, can I always assume an alignment of at least 8 bytes, then? And maybe, in practice, the alignment is even larger than this minimum because of some design choice?

What I would really like is a relatively-robust way to determine, hopefully at compile time and at worst at run time, a value that's as close to the actual minimum alignment of `malloc()` as I can.

**Notes:**

- If all else fails I don't mind doing something in my build script(s) to figure this out. But - it has to not be an educated guess (such as trying allocations at different sizes and seeing what happens). I need a solid guarantee.
- I'm assuming the minimum alignment is the same for `malloc()` and `realloc()`. If that's not the case then this is a two-part question...

Comment: Which problem do you want to solve here? Do you want to implement your own version of `malloc`?

Comment: @Gerhardh: For the sake of discussion, let's say I want to distinguish between cases when I have to manually align (and thus allocate a bit more) and cases when I get it for free. Also - what's it to you? I mean, it's not a contrived question regardless of my motivation.

Comment: As long as the library comes along with the compiler tool chain, the `malloc` function will always return an address that is aligned according to any data type supported by that compiler. Therefore I doubt that you really have to align it manually for any data type.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Maybe I want to align it to the size of the L1 cache? Or the size of VM page? etc.

Comment: GCC defaults to `2 * sizeof(size_t)`; however everything is a *compiler implementation detail*.

Comment: That is a valid request but then you don't need to care about alignment information of different toolchains. Aligning to special hardware requirements is outside the scope of C or the compiler. Therefore if you handle with large datatypes, you can rely on malloc. If you handle with hardware, you will most likely always have to do it manually.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Fine by me that it's an implementation detail, I want to know how to determine that detail - hopefully in my code, possibly in my build system.

Comment: I assume you know your alignment requirement, so if you can use C11 **and** if you don't care ending up with a larger alignment than you specify, how about using `aligned_alloc()` instead?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: That is a workaround to worrying about `malloc()`'s alignment (which I know about); but: 1. I'm still interested. 2. There's no `aligned_realloc()`

Comment: Hmm ... `void *aligned_realloc(void *old, size_t align, size_t oldsize, size_t size) { void *x = realloc(old, size); if (!x || x == old) return x; free(x); x = aligned_alloc(align, size); if (!x) return x; memcpy(x, old, oldsize); free(old); return x; }` <- possible UB here for using `old`, but it *might* work.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: This is getting off-topic, but - you're increasing the cost of `realloc()` by a factor of 2 in the worst case :-(

Comment: @einpoklum yes I know. But this is often an edge-case, of course depending on your allocation strategy and the implementation of `malloc()`. You might also want to just check the alignment of what `realloc()` gave you before throwing it away ;) maybe it is what you need already...

Comment: @FelixPalmen I think you should replace `free(x);` by `old=x;` because of subsequent `memcpy(x,old,oldsize); free(old);`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Uh, no, but I should throw away the whole comment, I overlooked that after a successful `realloc()`, `old` is already free'd.

Comment: @felixpalmen yes but it's content is still available as `x`. I don't see why it shouldn't work

Comment: Uhm, it should also take the maximum of `oldsize` and `size` for the `memcpy` ...

Comment: FYI: `max_align_t` which is an object type whose alignment is as great as is supported by the implementation in all contexts;` Example: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(max_align_t));` reports 24 on my machine.   So that seems to be an upper bound on the minimal (observable) needs of `malloc()`.

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504928/how-to-determine-the-minimum-alignment-of-malloc-results-on-my-system#comment77970908_45504928) , I think you want an answer to a different question than the post title. More like "How to determine the minimum alignment of a `my_malloc()` on my system?".  IOWs, code does not need to provide the minimum alignment that matches `malloc()` and friends, but needs to meet the minimum needs for an allocation.  `*alloc()` may be using n * the minimum needs.

Comment: Based on [`max_align_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504928/how-to-determine-the-minimum-alignment-of-malloc-results-on-my-system#comment77976246_45504928), code could use that for an _objective and portable_ alignment requirement.  That may not be the minimum, yet at least your allocator needs not be any higher.

Comment: @chux: `sizeof(max_align_t)` is irelevant (although I'm a bit irritated by that value). You need `_Alignof(max_align_t)`.

Answer (score 1):

In *C11* you should be able to use `_Alignof(max_align_t);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t a = _Alignof(max_align_t);
    printf("max alignment %zu\n", a);
}
```

[C11 6.2.8p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.8p2):

> **A fundamental alignment** is represented by an alignment less than or equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in all contexts, which is equal to `_Alignof (max_align_t)`.

and [C11 7.22.3p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3p1):

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object **with a fundamental alignment requirement**.

As I read it, the pointers returned from `malloc` must be  aligned to at least to `_Alignof(max_align_t)` on C11.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if `max_align_t` had not been introduced with C99 already, but `malloc` was required to return properly aligned memory at least since C99, most likely C89 or even earier. Anything else would just render it near useless for anything else than `char`s.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite it wasnt.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. One method I've seen used to try to do this portably is to create a union of several large types. Unions have the size of their largest member, so it should work as a pretty good proxy for the information you're looking for.

Richard Heathfield in C Unleashed goes through the process of building a memory tracking subsystem to help find memory leaks. He stores tracking metadata at the beginning of each allocation, but still has to ensure the payload is aligned suitably. To do so, on page 279, he creates a typedef'd type called ALIGN which is a union of a long, an unsigned long, a double, a long double, a void pointer, and a void function pointer taking void.

Comment: It is a bit strange solution. Same with macros: `#define MAX(a,b)  (((a) >= (b)) * (a) + ((b) > (a)) * (b))
#define MAXINTSIZE   MAX(sizeof(long), sizeof(long long))
#define MAXFLOATSIZE  MAX(sizeof(double), sizeof(long double))
#define MAXTYPE   MAX(MAXINTSIZE, MAXFLOATSIZE)`